# Small White Soapstone vs. White Soapstone

Tags: dark-souls-2-sotfs

I managed to acquire both a `Small White Sign Soapstone` and a `White Sign Soapstone`.

Before I sell the small version, I want to make sure that it's useless considering I have a normal soapstone.

I looked over both the wiki pages, and the small version just seems to be a more restricted version of the larger one.

Can I safely sell the small version if I have a `White Sign Soapstone`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This post](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/693331-dark-souls-ii/68787836) sums up the difference quite nicely.

> Small white sign soapstone puts the phantom in your world for around a 5 minute duration which when completed with or without a boss fight awards it's user a smooth and silky stone which is an item that can be traded with the crow for a random item or it can be used to heal yourself.
>
> Normal white sign soapstone has no time limit and lasts until you or the phantom dies, or you complete the boss and your reward is a token of fidelity which I'm not sure of it's use, but you need to have at least one on you for one convent.

Thus, if you value Smooth and Silky Stones to give to the Crows, you'd best keep *both* the Small White Sign Soapstone **and** the regular White Sign Soapstone.